# Procedure to insert employees: PL/SQL statement ignored

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to insert values into an `Employees` table using the following procedure. I'm getting errors. Can anyone please explain the problem to me? Error code: Line 29: SQL statement ignored.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_employee(
    p_emp_id IN NUMBER, 
    p_emp_fname IN VARCHAR2,
    p_emp_sname IN VARCHAR2,
    p_emp_add1 IN VARCHAR2, 
    p_emp_add2 IN VARCHAR2,
    p_emp_town IN VARCHAR2, 
    p_emp_county IN VARCHAR2,
    p_emp_telno IN NUMBER,
    p_emp_position IN VARCHAR2, 
    p_emp_manager IN VARCHAR2

) IS 
    v_county_id County.county_id%type;
    v_position_id Positions.position_id%type;
    v_manager_id Facilities.facilty_id%type;
BEGIN    

    SELECT county_id
    INTO v_county_id
    FROM County WHERE county_name = p_emp_county;

    SELECT position_id
    INTO v_position_id
    FROM Positions WHERE position_name = p_emp_position;

    SELECT facility_manager
    INTO v_manager_id
    FROM Facilities WHERE facility_name = p_emp_manager; 

    INSERT INTO Employees (emp_id, emp_fname, emp_sname, emp_add1, emp_add2, emp_town, emp_county, emp_telno, emp_position, emp_salary, emp_manager) 
    VALUES(p_emp_id, p_emp_fname, p_emp_sname, p_emp_add1, p_emp_add2, p_emp_town, v_county_id, p_emp_telno, v_position_id, p_emp_salary, v_manager_id);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the SELECTs - they are in invalid syntax, and don't do anything necessary here anyway.  ALso remove the pointless error "handler" which does nothing more than hide the error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_employee(
    p_emp_id IN NUMBER, 
    p_emp_fname IN VARCHAR2,
    p_emp_sname IN VARCHAR2,
    p_emp_add1 IN VARCHAR2, 
    p_emp_add2 IN VARCHAR2,
    p_emp_town IN VARCHAR2, 
    p_emp_county IN VARCHAR2,
    p_emp_telno IN NUMBER,
    p_emp_position IN VARCHAR2, 
    p_emp_manager IN VARCHAR2

) IS
BEGIN    

    INSERT INTO Employees (emp_id, emp_fname, emp_sname, emp_add1, emp_add2, emp_town, emp_county, emp_telno, emp_salary, emp_position, emp_manager) 
    VALUES(p_emp_id, p_emp_fname, p_emp_sname, p_emp_add1, p_emp_add2, p_emp_town, p_emp_county, p_emp_telno, p_emp_salary, p_emp_position, p_emp_manager);

 END;
```

If your example has been oversimplified and you actually need the values you were selecting before (e.g. you insert those into Employees also) then you need to use "select into" syntax e.g.

```
...
) IS
    v_county_id county.county_id%type;
    v_xxx county.xxx%type;
BEGIN    

    SELECT county_id
    INTO   v_county_id
    FROM County WHERE county_name = p_emp_county;
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks Tony, yeah I need the values that I was selecting. I had the syntax wrong so. Your 2nd block of code should be able to put those values into my Employee table correct?

Comment: Yes you can just use `v_county_id` (for example) in the VALUES clause of your insert statement exactly the same way you are using the parameters.

Comment: You need to terminate each variable declaration with a ";", not seperate them with commas. See my updated answer.

Comment: Still not working Tony, back to SQL ignored at line 29. Any other suggestions?!

Comment: Apologies to be so late replying. I have revised the code again. Thanks for all your help

Comment: Oddly, I find that I get that error (SQL statement ignored) when I try to compile that procedure when the table `Employees` does not exist.  Don't know why it doesn't just say "table or view does not exist".  So maybe `Employees` doesn't exist in your schema?

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me on this Tony. The Employees table does exist in my schema though, as do all of the fields that I reference. I have tried to identify any possible syntax/typing errors but to no avail!

Answer (score 2):

Your local variable declarations should have semicolons at the end of each line:

```
) IS 
    v_county_id County.county_id%type;
    v_position_id Positions.position_id%type;
    v_manager_id Facilities.facilty_id%type;
```

Comment: @adohertyd -- suggest you edit the question to include the error messages you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to select into a cursor or a variable?

E.g.

```
SELECT county_id into v_country
    FROM County WHERE county_name = p_emp_county;
```

Comment: The procedure is called, the user should enter all of the p_emp_ values. I want those values to then be attributed to a new employee. My `SELECT` statements are probably causing the issue but I don't know how to fix them

Answer (score 0):

you should type ; after variable definition instead comma.

Answer (score 0):

check column name

v_manager_id Facilities.**facilty**_id%type;

FROM Facilities WHERE **facility**_name = p_emp_manager;

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace procedure procOne(sid  OUT  number,sname OUT varchar,fee OUT number)
as
begin
insert into student values(sid,sname,fee);
end;
```